# Zend Framework - fetchAll returns fatal error when it has no rows returned?

Tags: zend-framework, fatal-error, fetchall

I know that when I try top use `fetchAll` and it returns a fatal error, the reason is because it has returned no records on the query. But my question is, how to treat it? How can I know if the query will not return any records, so i do not use `toArray()`?

For instance,

```
$table = new Application_Model_Proucts();
$products = $table->fetchAll()->toArray();
```

How can I do a verification of the query before I put the `toArray` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no records returned from `fetchAll()` then you are passing nothing to `toArray()`, which is where the error is occurring.

Try wrapping the last but of your code in an if statement:

```
$products = $table->fetchAll();

if(count($products))
{
  $products = $products->toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro, totally worked, with fetchRow and fetchAll as well.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your query in a condition and/or throw a new exception when condition isn't met